# for loop for finding smallest element in an Array

Tags: c, arrays, forms

Okay so my program is suppose to create an array size [8] and then once its printed I'm using a For loop to find the smallest number in the array. The problem i'm having is that it seems to always be stopping at the second element and declaring it as smallest. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
const int len = 8;
int a[len];
int i;



srand(time(0));

//Fill the array
for(i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    a[i] = rand() % 100;
}

//Print the array
for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    printf("%d ", a[i]);
}
printf("\n");
getchar();

int smallest;
for (i = 1; i < len; i++) {
    if (a[i] < smallest)
        smallest = a[i];
    {
        printf("The smallest integer is %d at position %d\n", a[i], i);
        break;
        getchar();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. `c#` and `c++` tags looks irrelevant. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code, like following :

1-The variable int smallest is used before initializing.
2- The logic inside last for loop is wrong.

The right code is :

```
void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const int len = 8;
    int a[len];
    int smallest;
    int location =1;
    int i;

    srand(time(0));

    //Fill the array
    for(i = 0; i < len; ++i) 
    {
       a[i] = rand() % 100;
    }

    //Print the array
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
      printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    smallest = a[0];

    for ( i= 1 ; i < len ; i++ ) 
    {
        if ( a[i] < smallest ) 
        {
           smallest = a[i];
           location = i+1;
        }
    } 
    printf("Smallest element is present at location %d and it's value is %d.\n",      location,    smallest );

    getch();
}
```

Comment: okay so my main mistake was initializing smallest right above my For loop instead of at the header. along with completely passing up on my declaration of a location variable. @AnkitPandey

Comment: Yes, there was some small problem with your code like -
1- Variable smallest should be initialized before used.
2- Logic inside the for loop was not correct
3- Break statements was used in incorrect position with incorrect logic..
@user3504208 - Please update your name rather using user3504208 :-)

Comment: Ya I'm really new to this programming language so it's taking me quite a while to understand everything but I'm starting to get the hang of it. I really appreciate you help. I had not realized my username was all weird like that. Thanks @AnkitPandey

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    printf("The smallest integer is %d at position %d\n", a[i], i);
    break;
    getchar();

}
```

This block gets executed at the same time as the `if` condition, which means you're breaking out of your loop as soon as you encounter an `a[i]` that's smaller than `smallest`.

As an aside, you probably want to initialize `smallest` to equal `a[0]` before you go into your loop.

Comment: The reason i had used a break was becasue it constantly repeated the printf statement and the only way i could figure off the top of my head to stop it was to break after it printed not realizing that it was stopping the entire program after only one run through. Thank you @jason

Answer (score 0):

```
Int smallest=a[0];
for (int i=1;i<len;i++)
{
     if(a[i]<smallest)
           Smallest=a[i];
}
```

Comment: I think my main problem was that i had a break; in my code as soon as it ran through one time to compare the first two numbers. My original work resembled what you have here. Thank you @JunaidShirwani

Comment: Yes break was the real problem, good to hear that your problem was solved.if you think my answer helped you ,accepting it would be nice

Comment: I am bot sure but you can give it a try